# XDomainRequest Errors, but developer tools shows response body

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-9, xdomainrequest

I am using XDomainRequest to send a cross domain request.  The onerror handler is firing; however, nothing is logged and when tracing network in developer tools I can see the response in the response body.

Anyone have any ideas?  Below is the code I am using.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
var createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
  // Most browsers.
  xhr.open(method, url, true);
} else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
  // IE8 & IE9
  xhr = new XDomainRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url);
} else {
  // CORS not supported.
  xhr = null;
}
return xhr;
};

var url = 'https://myurl';

var method = 'GET';
var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);

xhr.onload = function() {
  // Success code goes here.
  //alert("load");
alert(xhr.responseText);
};

xhr.onprogress = function(){
 alert("Progress");     
}

xhr.onerror = function() {

  alert("error");
};


xhr.send();
```

Comment: The request is failing. Why is it failing? Do you see the CORS header in the response headers? is the status-code 200? is the contentType correct?

Comment: Thats the thing, I don't see any headers coming back and IE shows the status as 0.  Like I said though, I can see the response body using Developer tools, just cant access it in the javascript.  Any way you know of debugging?

Comment: At the place where you see the response body, you should be able to also see headers.

Comment: If all else fails, install fiddler and inspect the response from there.

Comment: Yea, for some reason the response headers are empty.  IE developer tools are only showing the response Body.  I will install fiddler and see if that shows anything else.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I expect it to be a CORS issue, but without knowing what the browser is sending and what the server is responding with, it's going to be difficult to track down.

Answer (score 0):

XDomainRequest object does not provide anyway to determine what is the status code of error, and returns empty string in xdr.responseText.